# Why can a "hello world" c++ program raise so many "iosfwd" errors in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, iosfwd

I just typed this "hello world" c++ program in visual studio 2015 :

```
#include<iostream>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and then, vs told me :

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'fpos_t'   
Error   C3646   'seekpos': unknown override 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('       
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body      
Error   C3646   '_Fpos': unknown override specifier
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   C2065   'EOF': undeclared identifier
```

these errors had the same source:

```
f:\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\iosfwd
```

well, please ignore my file path. But `iosfwd` seems to be the core of problems? And one of the situations in `iosfwd` is: 
[Error  C2065   'EOF': undeclared identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ1ml.png)

I am searching for a long time. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

---

If i create a new `Win32 Console Application"` instead of `Empty Project`, and use `#include "stdafx.h"`(if I don't include"stdafx.h", it also goes wrong). Then my program runs successfully. So, what's the secret of visual studio.

Comment: Have you originally installed VS on drive F:\ or did you move it there ? Had once a similar problem when I moved my installation.

Comment: I think I didn't move it.

Comment: I tried your code with `Empty Project` and it worked fine. You could just stick with `Win32 Console Application`, but if you really want to use an `Empty Project`, I guess the first step is maybe to try re-installing Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe the Visual Studio project is configured to use a precompiled header file?  I think `#include "stdafx.h"` is needed when a precompiled header file is used.  VS uses a precompiled header by default, unless you tell it not to do so when creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Tried to include `<memory>` before `<iostream>`. The issue disappeared.